# Cycles render artifacts that looks like strings and web

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, artifacts

does anyone know how to get rid of these artifacts? They appear on only some of the frames and I have tested them with different samples, lighting, and shader.

[image]

Comment: Did you use a boolean modifier to attach those antennae to the forehead? Or possibly sculpted with dyntopo enabled?

Comment: @TitaniusAnglesmith It's a clean mesh with clean retopology. Other scenes seem fine so it seems like it's not a mesh problem...

Comment: Those were my only ideas, but as you say other scenes are fine, have you made sure those aren't shadows from other objects in your scene? Possibly something hidden in the viewport, but still visible in the render?

Comment: Yeah no,,, because it only happens in a few random frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off Motion blur. It has been buggy recently and lots of people are seeing these artefacts.

Comment: Yes, it's true! I turned the motion blur off and the artifacts were gone. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also,  "Auto-smooth" from "Object Data Properties"  off seems to work as well!